# PhoneGap/Android - Locking orientation to portrait

Tags: android, cordova, screen, orientation

I have tried every method to lock the screen to portrait orientation but they simply do not work after testing the app via Adobe PhoneGap Build.

Firstly, I have modified the MainActivity.java file to include at onCreate

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Secondly,  I have modified the config.xml file to include

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Thirdly, I have modified the Manifest file to include

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

None of the above are working.

Comment: I have just tested this through the Eclipse AVD and the screen orientation locks as intended. Any idea why this is not the case when running the app via PhoneGap Build?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using Cordova 3.4.1 `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` should work.

Also, don't forget to add: `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the activity tag.

Else, you can try using this plugin: https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock

Comment: Hey @zalow517, what is the "activity tag" you were refering to? (to add `android:configChanges="orientation"`)

Comment: Mentioned plugin is deprecated, use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32405384/1848600 , for Cordova 4.0 +

Comment: The Cordova docs show "Orientation" with a capital "O". Does that matter?

Comment: Be aware that these values are case sensitive, it is "Orientation", not "orientation".

Answer (score 26):

Update the config.xml File which is in your project folder, above www.

Add the line:-

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Then build you project & there will be no Orientation Change.

In place of "portrait" you can use "landscape".

Comment: Hi, doing this will lock the app in portrait, however, it seems the camera is not respecting that, the camera rotates to orientation of the device.

Comment: @olanchuy - Of course; the camera is a separate app.

Answer (score 2):

just put below in activity tag below application tag in android manifest.xml file

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Thanks

Comment: This gets regenerated and you must set the setting in the project.xml file as described above

Comment: This 100% did it for me.. nothing else.